# Can not change Database name in Products Configuration Wizard

Tags: configuration-wizard

I was given a small 2 server farm to see if I could get it going.  I have a front end/app server and an SQL server.

I ran windows updates on both and restarted.  When I try to run the SharePoint Product's Configuration Wizard, I get to a screen that shows the Configuration Database Server etc..  Well the Server it is pointing to is non-existent.  The problem is, I can put my cursor in the field but can not change the Server name nor the Database name. It just wont let me do anything in those boxes.

What do I do now ?

Thanks!!
Robert

Comment: Should you attach screen shot to your issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar issue, but with the instance name, that somehow was changed on the SQL Server...In my case it's still working because it's the same port for the instance and the servername didn't change. But is filling up the windows logs with a critical error saying that couldn't find the database server (althought the site is still working fine).

I did some research on the web and I found out that its NOT possible to change the database server or instance name of a farm that is already running, even tried to find some solution with Powershell or STSDAM, but found nothing. The solution is to build another farm from 0 pointing to the correct database servername/instance and then restore the content databases.

Also, there is a tip to avoiding this to happen and other SQL connection problems that is use an SQL ALIAS to point to the database server, instead of point directly to the servername/instance.

I think you can also try to disconnect and reconnect the servers to the farm, if you have the pass-phrase (don't do this without it!!!), and try to reconnect using an SQL ALIAS, but I'm not sure if this will work as expected (In my case I left the decision for my client as it's a production environment).